Broaden from quant to Finance / Accounting
I really like what is going on at quant.stackexchange, but I think in general a Finance specific (with quant questions as a general tag) or something for Accounting/Finance as these can be very intertwined.  There is a personal finance exchange, but, as per the name, it is limited to persons seeking individual help or the practitioners who help them, which is great.  There isn't something for people interested in corporate financial matters.
quant.stackexchange seems like a great site, but more scoped to a tag or general subsection than a stand-alone.
Thoughts?

No. The moment quant.se is populated with accounting/personal+general finance questions, people would flee. Quant Finance is a narrow niche and I'd like to keep it that way.

Quantitative finance has very little to do with corporate finance. The former is primarily about rigorously defined valuations (in one form or the other) whereas the latter is about capital decisions and strategy. Nobody leaves an accounting firm for a derivatives desk and vice-versa; they are totally different skill sets, goals, careers, cultures, etc.

Corporate Finance and Accounting is a critical part of building quantitative equity portfolios. For example - accruals factors, earnings growth, price-to-cashflow and hundreds of  other balance sheet and income statement characteristics are the starting points for building fundamental factor models.
Here are a couple topics that in my view legitimately cross into QE :
- questions around asset-pricing tests
- identification of what IS/BS variables are priced risk factors
- procedures to estimate equity risk premium 
Someone would have to better demarcate the boundary zone but seems to me there is room where Accounting and Finance overlap.

Hey, just wanted to let you know that some time ago (actually decision was based mostly on this topic) I've created a proposal for a separate Corporate Finance/Investment Banking site at Area51.
It's not very active right now, so there's no prospect of migrating questions soon, but if anyone's interested in broadening the scope of SE sites to non-quantitative finance, then feel free to follow. We will see if there's (any) interest in such topics.

There is this: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1897/taxation-and-accounting.  Doesn't really look at address your needs either.  
I just have a slightly hard time seeing this working well.  While I agree that the techniques, tools, and methods have a lot of overlap, the communities tend not to.  I think that it might be more appropriate to try to generate interest in a separate Accounting site.
That being said, in my view, you should go ahead and post a representative question here and see whether people will accept it.  I view the site development process as an emergent process.
